# Isometric in stochastic integral.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

If $\{X_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ is a simple process. i.e.$0=t_0\le t_1\le\cdots\le t_n=T$

$\exists \xi_i\in\mathcal F_{t_i}$ s.t.$X_t(\omega)=\xi_i(\omega)$ when $t\in[t_i,t_{i+1}].$

$\{W_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ is a B.M. So we have:
$$\mathbb E\left[(\int_0^T X_t\text{d}W_t)^2\right]=\mathbb E\left[\int_0^TX_t^2\text{d}t\right]$$

I want to prove it:
$$(\int_0^T X_t\text{d}W_t)^2=(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\xi_i(W_{i+1}-W_i))^2=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\xi_i\xi_j(W_{i+1}-W_i)(W_{j+1}-W_j)$$

if $i\neq j$,$(W_{i+1}-W_i)$and$(W_{j+1}-W_j)$ are independent.

If $$\mathbb E\left[\xi_i\xi_j(W_{i+1}-W_i)(W_{j+1}-W_j)\right]=\mathbb E\left[\xi_i\xi_j\right]\mathbb E\left[(W_{i+1}-W_i)(W_{j+1}-W_j)\right]$$
then I can finish the proof,how to obtain this equation ?(there is no information about independence)

Comment: "there is no information about independence" *There should be*, namely that $(X_t)$ is *adapted*, in particular, if $i\lt j$, hence $\xi_i\xi_j(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i})$ and $W_{t_{j+1}}-W_{t_j}$ are independent hence...

Comment: ?? Of course, $F_i$ and $F_j$ are **not** independent.

Comment: @Did Could you give me more hints?I don't know how to get"$\xi_i\xi_j(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})$ and $(W_{t_{j+1}}-W_{t_j})$ are independent" according to "$X_t$ is adapted."

Comment: Here is a hint: The first one is measurable with respect to some sigma-algebra of which the second one is independent by the very definition of Brownian motion.

Comment: @Did Perhaps I misunderstand what you mean.The two items mentioned above can not be independent.Otherwise,$\mathbb E\left[\xi_i\xi_j(W_{i+1}-W_i)(W_{j+1}-W_j)\right]=\mathbb E\left[\xi_i\xi_j(W_{i+1}-W_i)\right]\mathbb E\left[(W_{j+1}-W_j)\right]=0$.It is impossible.

Comment: O yeah? And why is this impossible?

Comment: @Did Then the LHS of the isometric equality is $0$ for arbitrary $X$.

Comment: No, because all the terms $i=j$ remain.

Comment: @Did thanks，I got it.The increment is independent of the previous sigma algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $i < j$. Note that 
$$
\begin{split}
E\left[\xi_i\xi_j(W_{i+1}-W_i)(W_{j+1}-W_j)\right] 
&= 
E\left[
E\left[\xi_i\xi_j(W_{i+1}-W_i)(W_{j+1}-W_j)|\mathcal F_{t_j}\right] 
\right]
\\
&=
E\left[\xi_i\xi_j(W_{i+1}-W_i)
E\left[(W_{j+1}-W_j)|\mathcal F_{t_j}\right] 
\right]
\\
&=
0
\end{split}
$$
By symmetry $i > j$ will be $0$ as well.

For $i=j$, 
$$
\begin{split}
E\left[\xi_i^2(W_{i+1}-W_i)^2\right]
&=
E\left[E\left[\xi_i^2(W_{i+1}-W_i)^2|\mathcal F_{t_i}\right]\right]
\\
&=
E\left[\xi_i^2 E\left[(W_{i+1}-W_i)^2|\mathcal F_{t_i}\right]\right]
\\
&=
E\left[\xi_i^2 \right](t_{i+1} - t_i)
\\
\end{split}
$$

We have 
$$
\begin{split}
E\left[\left(\int_0^T X_t\text{d}W_t\right)^2\right]
&=
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}E\left[\xi_i\xi_j(W_{i+1}-W_i)(W_{j+1}-W_j)\right]
\\
&=
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} E\left[\xi_i^2 \right](t_{i+1} - t_i)
\\
&=
E\left[\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \xi_i^2 (t_{i+1} - t_i)\right]
\\
&=
E\left[\int_0^T X_t^2 dt\right]
\\
\end{split}
$$